# How to customize MPAndroidChart library according to custom design requirements

Tags: android, charts, mpandroidchart

I am creating an application and I want to customize some existing android pie chart library according to custom design needs.

I am using MAPAndroidChart Library and successfully created initial Pie Design as follows
[image]

But when it comes to design implementation, it requires some design customizations in design, Required designs are somewhat similar to following images

[image]
[image]

Can someone guide me if there is any possibility to modify MAPAndroid Chart library or if there is some other library which will support such customization.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: of course there is possibility to modify it, you just type on terminal: `git clone https://github.com/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart.git` and go ahead and modify it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way to achieve the scenario you described with MPAndroidChart **by default**. However, as Budius already mentioned in his comment, there is always the possibility to clone the library and **modify it in any way you want** in order to fit your needs.

Instructions on cloning can be found here: https://github.com/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart#usage

Comment: make sense, Thanks Philipp and Budius